# Issues with getter and setter methods for my contact class

Tags: java

I am having issues with my getter and setter methods for my contact class. Could someone help me better understand these methods? Thanks here's my code I have so far for my contact class getter and setter methods

```
public class Contact {

      public static void main (String []args){

      }

      private String name;

      private String email;



      //constructor, validates the email to make sure the '@' character is present

      Contact(String name, String email){

            this.name = name;

            if(email.indexOf("@") >= -1)

                  System.out.println("invalid email");

            else 

                  this.email = email;

      }

      //method points out the contact's name and email

      void getContactList(){

            System.out.println(name + "" + email);

      }

      //setter method for name

      void getname(String name){

                  this.name = name;

      }

      //setter method for email

      void getemail(String email){

            this.email = email;

      }

      //getter method for name

      //getter method for email

  }
```

Comment: what issue are you facing?

Comment: Why on earth are you calling your set methods "getfoo"?  Following standard naming conventions will make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: Dude. Your two "setter" methods are named `getname(String name)` and `getemail(String email)`... That is wrong in and of itself. Secondly, getters are supposed to return a value, not println one.

Comment: Better to use the functionality of generating get/setters provided by your IDE, if you're not writing your codes in a Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Getters and setters are implemented like so:

```
// setter
void setFoo(Foo foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}

// getter
Foo getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
```

Currently your "getter" is actually a setter, and you haven't implemented a getter.

Answer (score 0):

Getter/setter pairs are a common way to make variables secure by setting them to private. You can get the vlaue of an object's variable with `getVar` and set the value with `setVar(Obj value)`.

Your code could be repaired like so:

```
public class Contact {

private String name;

private String email;



//constructor, validates the email to make sure the '@' character is present

public Contact(String name, String email){

    this.name = name;

    if(email.indexOf("@") == -1) { //@ not present
          System.out.println("invalid email");
          this.email = null;
    }

    else 
          this.email = email;

}

//method points out the contact's name and email

public String getContactList(){

    return name + "" + email;

}

//setter method for name

public void setName(String name){

          this.name = name;

}

//setter method for email

public void setEmail(String email){

    this.email = email;

}

//getter method for name
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
//getter method for email
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
}
```

I highly recommend you do some more research on common Java paradigms before you begin making programs. Check out what a Java Bean is, what access types are, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for all of the feedback. I am new to java I am still learning how everything works with one another.